# Class QSqlError has no member nativeErrorCode()

Tags: c++, qt5, qsqldatabase

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a while, and unfortunately neither my own reasoning, nor google search helped me. In simple terms, I am trying to use nativeErrorCode() function with QSqlError class. Compiler says: mainwindow.cpp:43:86: error: ‘class QSqlError’ has no member named ‘nativeErrorCode’. This is the line that it references (to be exact, two lines):

```
errorCreatingBooksTableMessageBox.setDetailedText((query.lastError().nativeErrorCode().isEmpty()) ?
                query.lastError().text() : query.lastError().nativeErrorCode() + "\n" + query.lastError().text());
```

Problem seems trivial, but I can't find an answer on my own. #include  is in mainwindow.h file. After some research, I noticed other people on other forums suggesting that compiler uses wrong version of the header file, which would seem very likely to happen since function nativeErrorCode() was introduced in Qt5. I tried to move qt4 folder to trash, but still, no effect. Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which OS you encounter this issue. However In most of the Linux OS Image, prebuild with Qt4, Even we build Qt5 libraries additionally, the system environment may use old Qt4 libraries to generate make files. This is very common if we are building Qt5 from source codes.  So it would be better you can try to execute qmake from Qt5 path. So the *Makefile* will be created to build for Qt5 libraries.

In order to confirm, Open the *Makefile* and check the variable *QMAKE* is refering to Qt5 or Qt4 libraries.

I am updating this from my system for your reference, **"QMAKE  = /home/user1/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake"**  From this, It is clear that Makefile is using Qt5 libraries and further compilation, Qt5 libraries will be used to compile my application source code.

Comment: COpied from my makefile: QMAKE         = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake

Comment: If that is the case, you are using Qt5,  did you include #include <QSqlError> ?

Comment: I believe so ://

Comment: Please, anyone any suggestions??